# What's the difference between using the ActiveMQ MasterSlave Discovery and Shared Config?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, high-availability

On the activemq [MasterSlave page](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html), they introduce a few ways for setting that up using either **JDBC**, **Shared File**, or **LevelDB Store**.

However, on the [Network of Brokers](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html) page, they talk about the **MasterSlave Discovery** without the need of setting up one of the shared configuration (JDBC, File, or LevelDB Store).

```
<networkConnectors>
  <networkConnector uri="masterslave:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616,tcp://..)"/>
</networkConnectors>
```

What are the differences between using the **MasterSlave Discovery** and **Shared Configuration**? When should I should one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC, Shared File or Replicated LevelDB are all options to create a high available persistance store that can be access by masters and it's slave(s). Note that LevelDB store is not Shared, but replicated.

If you want to connect a broker via network connection (network of brokers) to another logical broker that consists of a master and a slave, the `masterslave:` uri prefix is a shorthand for the [failover](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) prefix with less typing.

So, MasterSlave Discovery and Shard Configuration are totally different things.

What you should compare is instead a shared persistence store (JDBC, Shared file) vs a [replicated LevelDB store](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html) (share nothing). The later will allow you to setup totally independent brokers that act as a failover cluster, without the need to share a disk or database.

Answer (score 0):

one issue if you are using the masterslave discovery uri
that is the cpu is high usage (>90%)
the workaround way

Answer (score -1):

There is an interesting discussion going on ActiveMQ user forum about the same : http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Avoiding-shared-state-between-master-and-slave-brokers-td4686401.html

I am also confused about this : 
Is there any way to achieve **shared nothing fully replicated** configuration in a network of brokers wherein there is only one master at a time and all clients are connected to this one instance (with support for reelection of new master when current master goes away)?